# Overlaying custom badge for each profile on Firefox icon on OS X

Tags: macos, firefox, firefox-extensions, dock

I am using [profilist](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/profilist/) to switch between profiles without docking an additional icon, and I would like to be able to distinguish the icons by overlaying a custom badge on each of them, but I cannot find an extension to do that. I know that I could create [one app launcher for each profile](http://spf13.com/post/managing-multiple-firefox-profiles-in-os-x) but I was wondering if there was a self-contained method.

Sketch of the idea:

[image: Sketch of the idea]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I had to [give it a try](https://github.com/evacchi/firefox-custom-badge). The result may not be as nice as my mockup 
but it works for me!

[image: screenie]

Find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/evacchi/firefox-custom-badge)